# UIButton does not respond to tap when added inside a subview on UIWindow

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiwindow, touch-up-inside

I have a pop-up that I need to show on UIWindow. The pop-up has 3 buttons. The pop-up is perfectly added to the window but the buttons on the pop-up does not respond to touch.

Here is my code to add pop-up to window:

```
let windowCount = UIApplication.shared.windows.count
UIApplication.shared.windows[windowCount-1].insertSubview(blurView, at: (UIApplication.shared.windows.last?.subviews.count)!)
```

Code to pop-up

```
func setUpHelpMenu(){

            blurView.addSubview(backView)
            _ = backView.anchorPoints(left: blurView.leftAnchor, bottom: blurView.bottomAnchor, right: blurView.rightAnchor,  leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 10, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: blurView.frame.width, heightConstant: 170/812 * blurView.frame.size.height)

            backView.addSubview(resendCode)
            backView.addSubview(editPhoneNumber)
            backView.addSubview(cancel)

            _ = resendCode.anchorPoints(backView.topAnchor, centerX: backView.centerXAnchor, widthConstant: backView.frame.size.width, heightConstant: backView.frame.size.height / 3)
            _ = editPhoneNumber.anchorPoints(resendCode.bottomAnchor, centerX: backView.centerXAnchor, widthConstant: backView.frame.size.width, heightConstant: backView.frame.size.height / 3)
            _ = cancel.anchorPoints(editPhoneNumber.bottomAnchor, centerX: backView.centerXAnchor, widthConstant: backView.frame.size.width, heightConstant: backView.frame.size.height / 3 - 10)
        }
```

Code for the cancel button design:

```
let cancel: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.buttonTitleLabelWith(titleEdgeInsets: .zero, title: String(string: "Cancel") as NSString, lineBreakMode: .byWordWrapping, font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 25/1024 * UIScreen.main.bounds.height), textColor:  UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(0.80))
        button.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        button.backgroundColor = .blue
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tapPopUpButtons), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()
```

I have checked other similar questions on SO, but none worked in my case. Let me know where I am wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried setting clipsToBounds property of backview to true to see if your buttons are clipping or not?

Comment: key window catches user interaction first. So if there is multiple windows you have added to your app and want pop up to appear on specific window, make that window key window using `makeKeyAndVisible` else use `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow` to add popup view

Comment: @SandeepBhandari, you mean I should make this window `UIApplication.shared.windows[windowCount-1]` keyAndVisible ?

Comment: @sushil-sharma : Do you have multiple windows in your app? Custom ones you added? You can always use `isKeyWindow` to find if your window is key or not. For example : `if ! UIApplication.shared.windows[windowCount-1]. isKeyWindow { //then make your window key}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the answer. I was adding selector to the button on wrong place. Removed this code

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tapPopUpButtons), for: .touchUpInside)
```

from `UIButton` closure and added to `viewDidLoad` worked.